# Spring Boot JPA with not a well known database

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, teiid

I am trying to write Spring Boot application to connect to a Teiid database, I want to use JPA layer on it. I have configured the JDBC Data Source, but since this not well-known database in Spring JPA libraries do not autodetect this source. I have manually setup "spring.jpa.*" properties too. I do have a Hibernate dialect for this database, and it is on the classpath.

So, how does one need to configure JPA layer for a not well-known database in Spring Boot? Thank you for your time.

Ramesh..

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly well defined in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-configure-datasource).

You can set this explicitly in the `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
spring.datasource.username=dbuser
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```